# How do I make this logic circuit (A+B)' (B+D)' using NAND gates only?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

What I have done so far:

\begin{align*}
(A + B)'(B + D)' = A'B'B'D' = (A + B  + D)'
\end{align*}

I always get stuck at this point, I don't know what to do next that would allow me to use the NAND gates.

I would appreciate any hints or answers

Comment: If the prime means not then isn't $(A+B)'$ already a nand gate?

Comment: You could use that A' = (AA)' and then A+B = (A' B')'

Comment: A'B'D'=nand(nand(A'B',D'),nand(A'B',D')) where A'B'=nand(nand(A',B'),nand(A',B'))

Comment: @JohnDouma $(A+B)'$ is a NOR gate since $+$ means OR.

Answer (score 1):

If we start from your last relation:
\begin{align}
(A+B+D)'&=A'B'D'\\&=\left(\left(A'B'D'\right)'\right)'
\end{align}
Here, we have only NAND gates. $A'$ can be implemented as a NAND gate (with $A$ and $A$ as input signals). To build the 3-way NAND from 2-way NAND gates, you can do something like:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211756/how-to-build-a-3-input-nand-gate-from-2-input-nand-gates-or-a-3-input-nor-gate-f

So you need 7 gates here (assuming 2-way gates), maybe there are other solutions with fewer gates.